# Laravel 4.1.* issue registering events in service provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to register events with the service provider but I keep getting reflection class error. I have searched and could not find a solution, perhaps this is an issue with the core.

```
// AppServiceProvider.php

<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Events\UserEventHandler;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {

        // Events
        $this->app->events->subscribe(new UserEventHandler);

    }

}

// UserEventHandler.php

<?php namespace App\Events;

class UserEventHandler {

/**
 * Handle user login events.
 */
public function onUserLogin($event)
{
    echo 'subscriber logged in'; exit;
}

/**
 * Register the listeners for the subscriber.
 *
 * @param  Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher  $events
 * @return array
 */
public function subscribe($events)
{
    $events->listen('auth.login', 'UserEventHandler@onUserLogin');
}

}
```

`$this->app->events->subscribe(new UserEventHandler);` is firing fine, because I can reach the subscribe method, however  `$events->listen('auth.login', 'UserEventHandler@onUserLogin');` is returning an exception `Class UserEventHandler does not exist`

I have tried the same code on global.php and works fine, so the problem lies on the ServiceProvider, I have tried both methods register() and boot() and get the same error.

[UPDATED]

I have found that you need to specifically specify the full namespace when listening for the event.

```
public function subscribe($events)
{
    $events->listen('auth.login', 'App\Events\UserEventHandler@onUserLogin');
}
```

Comment: Did you `composer-dump` after you added the class ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried all composer dump-autoload, php artisan dump-autoload and nothing, the class does exists and is indeed instantiating, like I said I can reach the subscribe method however is not injecting itself when you pass `$events->listen('auth.login', 'UserEventHandler@onUserLogin');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare the full path to the class if it is in a different directory to the service provider.